# Ubuntu .bashrc custom PS1 behaving strange

Tags: bash, customization

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 and this is my custom PS1:

```
PS1="\n\[\033[0;90m\]\t \[\033[01;32m\]\e[1m\u@\h\e[m:$ \[\033[0;33m\w\n\e[1m\[\033[1;31m\]➤\e[m "
```

I am getting this weird text wrapping effect, when I use the arrow up key to summon the last command I typed, it creates an overlap effect oO! Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i had to do it on my own so here it is. 
so i did do this custom PS1 for like 5 years back or so, and that's why it's all fucked up, by the help of this well elaborated [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-bash-prompt-on-a-linux-vps) i fixed it so here it is:

```
 PS1="\n\[\e[0;90m\]\t \[\e[01;32m\]\u@\h:$ \[\e[0;33m\]\w\n\[\e[1;31m\]➤ \[\e[0;37m\]"
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not enclose all the non-printing characters in `\[...\]`, and I think you want to leave things like `\w` *unenclosed*.

```
PS1="\n\[\033[0;90m\]\t \[\033[01;32m\]\e[1m\u@\h\e[m:$ \[\033[0;33m\w\n\e[1m\[\033[1;31m\]➤\e[m "
                                       ^^^^^                        ^^                      ^^^^
```

Comment: 1st of all thanks for answering but why can't you just write the correct line please

Comment: Because you'll learn more by fixing it yourself, rather than just copy-and-pasting a pre-corrected line.